# Replace the values of a few properties of a big POCO object?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Linq

```
from s in ss // ss has the type of List<POCOWithALotOfColumns>
join x in xs
on new { RC = s.A, ID = s.B} equals new { RC = x.A, ID = x.B}
select s; // s.W and s.Z need to be replaced by the values in x.W and x.Z
```

It should show only the items exist both in `ss` and `xs`. And also a couple of fields in `s` need to be replaced by the values in `x`. How to implement it?

Since there are a lot of columns in `s`, is it a way to avoid to generate a new object by

```
select new S {
  ....... many lines ...., 
  W = x.W, 
  Z = x.Z
}
```

In F# it has

```
s with { W = x.W; Z = x.Z }
```

Comment: Does the F# `with` operator create a new object?

Comment: @NetMage Since "objects" (called records in F#) are immutable, implicitly yes.

Comment: Probably the most "C#"-ish way would be to have the object in question implement `ICloneable`, then call `myObject.Clone()` and mutate the fields on the result. That still requires you to do field copying/mapping though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using Reflection (which can be slow) then you can write an extension to simulate `With`. Mine uses some extensions I already have for making working with properties or fields easier:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static T With<T,TUpdate>(this T src, TUpdate upd) where T : new() {
        var ans = new T();
        var srcpfs = typeof(T).GetPropertiesOrFields();
        var updpfd = typeof(TUpdate).GetPropertiesOrFields().ToDictionary(pf => pf.Name);
        foreach (var srcpf in srcpfs)
            srcpf.SetValue(ans, updpfd.TryGetValue(srcpf.Name, out var updpf) ? updpf.GetValue(upd) : srcpf.GetValue(src));

        return ans;
    }

    // ***
    // *** Type Extensions
    // ***
    public static List<MemberInfo> GetPropertiesOrFields(this Type t, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
        t.GetMembers(bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field | mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).ToList();

    // ***
    // *** MemberInfo Extensions
    // ***
    public static object GetValue(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return mfi.GetValue(srcObject);
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.GetValue(srcObject);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo or PropertyInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }
    public static T GetValue<T>(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) => (T)member.GetValue(srcObject);

    public static void SetValue<T>(this MemberInfo member, object destObject, T value) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                mfi.SetValue(destObject, value);
                break;
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                mpi.SetValue(destObject, value);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo or PropertyInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can just use the extension `With`:

```
from s in ss // ss has the type of List<POCOWithALotOfColumns>
join x in xs
on new { RC = s.A, ID = s.B} equals new { RC = x.A, ID = x.B}
select s.With(new { x.W, x.Z }); // s.W and s.Z need to be replaced by the values in x.W and x.Z
```